# Как записать строки в PL/SQL курсор в определенном порядке?

Tags: oracle, plsql, курсор

Не понимаю, как записать в курсор строки в определенном, заданным некоторым условием, порядке. Т.е. интересующая строка должна попасть в результат запроса в любом случае, но требуется, чтобы она была именно последней в курсоре.

Нужную сортировку подабрать не удалось, условие поставновки на последнее место определяется значением, которое лежит в одном из полей этой строки (в примере ниже условие `s.service_synonym = 'AutoCloseOrder'`).

Пробовал через `UNION`, но он все равно не помещает нужную строку в конец курсора:

```sql
create or replace procedure get_service2(p_document_id number, res out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
  open res for
  select s.service_id, s.service_synonym from document d
  join service s on d.service_id = s.service_id
  where d.document_id = p_document_id and (s.service_synonym <> 'AutoCloseOrder' or s.service_synonym is null) 
  union
  select s.service_id, s.service_synonym from document d
  join service s on d.service_id = s.service_id
  where d.document_id = p_document_id and s.service_synonym = 'AutoCloseOrder';
  --order by s.service_synonym desc;   
end get_service2;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN (условие) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это ошибка, считать, что запись последнего подзапроса в `UNION` будет выведена последней. `UNION` неявно сортирует предварительный результат по всем в нём присутствующим колонкам с целью устранения дубликатов.

Хорошо, но многие же знают об этом и выключают неявное устранение дубликатов с `UNION ALL`. В этом случае, результат вроде выглядит, как ожидаемый (допустим нас интересует строка `name=b`):

```
create table t (id primary key, name) as 
    select rownum, trim (column_value) from xmlTable ('"a","b","c"')
/    

select t.* from t where name!='b' 
union all  
select t.* from t where name='b' 
/

        ID NAME
---------- ----
         1 a   
         3 c   
         2 b
```

Но это тоже ошибка, к тому же трудно диагностируемая, потому что порядок записей этого результата не гарантируется, ни стандартом SQL, ни документацией. Другими словами, сегодня порядок такой, завтра другой.

Порядок записей в результате запроса гарантируется только с `ORDER BY`, исключений нет:

```
select * 
from t 
order by case name when 'b' then 1 else 0 end, id
/

        ID NAME
---------- ----
         1 a   
         3 c   
         2 b
```